# How do I show an array of values in plantuml?

Tags: arrays, plantuml, state-diagram

I have an state diagram. At one point is gets into the `ListenToEvents` state. But the events can be updated. depending on the previous states.

In my plantUml file I have these to show which events the app listens to:

```
map Events {
  1 => EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD
}
```

and

```
map Events {
  1 => EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD
  2 => EVENT_TIMER_EXPIRATION
}
```

But I don't want to use associative arrays. I want to do something like

```
array Events {
  EVENT_PROFILE_DOWNLOAD
  EVENT_TIMER_EXPIRATION
}
```

I thought about using `object` instead of array, but then I get a syntax error

Basic example: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/dL6nJiCm4Dtz5KzPc3h0Y4hKYXefKaYgD0AsoAGM3OhjgZx3KFNVSLqh3KWTw9JBk_VUtJtFB8aTETKpNv14Q_hrwWXXpu2R39_E4hw59WZOJd_qWUEK1ebt_xEHE-cPIcp1lwGc6uJ0BHvIy1TUrCsoAf-od3UByhN8o_d2zm_i40ScVMT9Qf213Fe4mk84Hah07pUcQoMcqpOKQShOUTV991qaajns32ZHwToONzZf4v2HEHlLeHUyxYzTyPST1ms2EdlcLSFVbbarhxEoOF6Su7f5l0a_vxCwUlmZR-3Ezoyi5jyZhZVajVVOJEgrK_qF